# ValueAnimator only repeats once

Tags: java, android, animation, seekbar

I am trying to get a `ValueAnimator` to repeat once it has ended.  I am using it with a `SeekBar` in a `ListView`.  For some reason, the `ValueAnimator` will finish, trigger the `onAnimationEnd()` go again, but then when it reaches the end the `onAnimationEnd()` is never called a second time.

```
    @Override
    public View getContentView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        setupTimerBar(t);
        ...
    }


    private AnimatorListenerAdapter generateNewAnimatorListenerAdapter(final TylersContainer t) {
        return new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                setupTimerBar(t);
            }
        };
    }

    private void setupTimerBar(TylersContainer t)
    {       
        View view = t.getView();
        BusTime arrivalTime = t.getBusTime();
        int minutes = BusTime.differenceInMiuntes(arrivalTime, BusTime.now());
        long milliseconds = minutes * 60 * 1000;

        final TimerBar seekBar = (TimerBar) view.findViewById(R.id.SeekBar);

        int progress = Utility.setProgress(arrivalTime, seekBar.getMax());  
        long duration = Utility.setAnimationDuration(progress);

        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        seekBar.setAnimationDuration(duration);
        seekBar.setAnimationStartDelay(milliseconds);
        seekBar.setAnimatorListenerAdapter(generateNewAnimatorListenerAdapter(t));
    }
```

---

The `seekBar` object is actually an custom object which contains a `SeekBar` and a `ValueAnimator`, here are the relevant bits:

```
    //Constructor
    public TimerBar(Context context) {
        super(context);

        startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, getMax());

        //Override the update to set this object progress to the animation's value
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {    
                int animProgress = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                setProgress(animProgress);

            }
         });
    }

    //Specify the start time by passing a long, representing the delay in milliseconds
    public void setAnimationStartDelay(long milliseconds){

        //Set the delay (if need be) and start the counter
        if(milliseconds > 0)
            valueAnimator.setStartDelay(milliseconds);

        valueAnimator.setIntValues(this.getProgress(), this.getMax());

        valueAnimator.start();
    }


    //Set the duration of the animation
    public void setAnimationDuration(long duration){
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    }


    public void setAnimatorListenerAdapter(AnimatorListenerAdapter ala){
        valueAnimator.addListener(ala);
    }
```

---

I can't figure out why it isn't repeating more than twice.

I've tried using the `Repeat` attribute and setting that to `INIFINITI` but that didn't help either.

---

Edit:  To be clear, what I am trying to get is an animation that repeats itself indefinitely, each time with a different duration.

Comment: Some questions: What is `TylersContainer`? Why do you add a new listener every time `setupTimerBar` is executed, and never remove any? Why do you invoke `setAnimatorListenerAdapter` after `setAnimationStartDelay`? How did you verify `onAnimationEnd` is only called once?

Comment: `TylersContainer` is an object that holds a view and a time of when the next bus is coming (which is displayed in that view).  I added a new listener every time because thats how it was done in the example I found, I also didm't know you had to remove listeners, I thought they just were removed after completion.  The order of `setAnimationListenerAdapter` and `setAnimationStartDelay` was trivial.  I verify that `onAnimationEnd` is only being called once with some print statements to log cat.

Comment: "The order of setAnimationListenerAdapter and setAnimationStartDelay was trivial." I asked as I'm not sure if it is possible that `onAnimationEnd` is called before the listener has been added. In general, you could try to step through your code's execution using the debugging capabilities of android. Maybe that yields results?

Comment: Thanks for some clues, will do

Comment: As @dst pointed out, I guess you need to rearrange `setAnimationStartDelay()` and `setAnimatorListenerAdapter()`, you will get in trouble in case duration and start delay are 0.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends did you check my answer, any comments?

Answer (score 26):

I have made the error of setting the `RepeatMode` to infinite which did not work, this must be set as the `RepeatCount`:

```
valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `Animator`, and then bind it with `Animator.AnimatorListener`

The function `AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd()` is used in case your animation repeats for finite times, and **is only called once**

In case your animation is repeating, for number of times, you should be using the function `AnimatorListener.onAnimationRepeat()` instead, which will apply everytime your animation **repeats after the end of each repeatance**

From what I understand, what you need is `onAnimationRepeat()`, so if you just move the code that you want to be executed after each repeat from `onAnimationEnd()` to `onAnimationRepeat()`, this should fix it

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html